# Linking to sources from scaladoc?

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to link to sources on github from my scaladoc. I build those docs with the sbt's `doc` task.

There are two problems - first, I do not like creating several nested empty directories for my `.scala` files, so I usually pack them all in one - like `src/main/scala/org.rogach.scallop` instead of `src/main/scala/org/rogach/scallop`. Is there a way to make links to docs work without splitting that directory?

Second, when I put this line in my build.sbt:

```
scalacOptions in (Compile, doc) ++=
  Opts.doc.sourceUrl("https://raw.github.com/Rogach/scallop/master/src/main/scala/")
```

docs contain links to sources, but all those links just point to the source root url, not files themselves. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the output of `scaladoc help`:

```
-doc-source-url <url>        A URL pattern used to build links to template
                             sources; use variables, for example:
                               €{TPL_NAME} ('Seq'),
                               €{TPL_OWNER} ('scala.collection'),
                               €{FILE_PATH} ('scala/collection/Seq')
```

(Yes that is the euro symbol.)

Something like the following should work as an argument to sourceUrl if all of your sources are defined in a package:

```
https://raw.github.com/Rogach/scallop/master/src/main/scala/€{TPL_OWNER}.€{TPL_NAME}.scala
```

Comment: It almost worked - for all classes, names of which are equal to names of files where they are defined. But since I put several classes into the same file, this breaks :(

Comment: I settled on using FILE_PATH and replacing the prefix of the project directory on my machine with `sed` expression. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, I didn't suggest that because it is difficult to get working correctly.  See also https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5763.