# Generate Scala Docs with integrated source codes?

Tags: scala, sbt

I switched to Scala some time ago and I love it. I use SBT as my build tool and really enjoy the beautiful generate API docs with "sbt doc".

But I wonder if there is a way (for example a plugin) that enriches the generated documentation HTML files to include the actual source code. Kind of like  the way http://grepcode.com shows source code with nice interlinking of class names and so on.

If anyone has an idea. And if there is no solution out there, maybe this would be a nice open source SBT plugin to start...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419227/linking-to-sources-from-scaladoc - does this answer your question?

Comment: It's a start. This solution would only redirect to a link with the source. On the page were I can see the sources then, I cannot click on a class name and get redirected to the next source file. But still, I will try this out tomorrow. Thank you!